# Chabad Kollel for Frum from birth

Tags: chabad, kollel

does anyone happen to know of any Chabad Kollelim for ffb people? I've been looking and all I can find is morristown but its for BT's. If anyone knows would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think there's one in Brooklyn, on Eastern Parkway. I'm afraid I can't seem to recall the exact street address, though.

Comment: would you happen to know the name?

Comment: He's probably thinking of Kollel Menachem on Kingston.